# Bundle command not found error in capistrano deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I am using capistrano deployment.

These errors i m getting after cap deploy

```
Command 'bundle' is available in '/usr/local/bin/bundle'
The command could not be located because '/usr/local/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
bundle: command not found
```

Please help

Comment: are you using rvm? rbenv? post your deploy.rb file and gemfile

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add the /user/local/bin folder to the path on the target system.  Whatever login you are logging in as with Capistrano, find the profile that contains the path, and add it.

Or, add /usr/local/bin to the master path (the actual file depends on the operating system and version.  If you provide the operating system and shell, we can tell you the file to look for)